# Why GDB (or any debugger) steps into headers?

Tags: c++, debugging, header, gdb

I am self learning C++ for hardly 2 weeks so although this is a very basic question be kind. Now, as I understand headers play completely no role during a program's runtime. Headers are used solely by compilers during compilation. Still when debugging (I am using GDB) the program the debugger steps into headers. And when also using a disassembly while debugging I noticed those header steps actually represent assembly instructions (like 'mov' etc.). But headers should not even exist in binaries. So exactly what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"source files" are used exclusively by compilers during compilation too, although if you ask a compiler nicely, it will place debug symbols in a compiled binary that will contain program source file **and** header file data.

There's nothing magical about "headers". They are merely used by convention and `#include`d by a *preprocessor* directive by one or more "source files". And it's this "or more" that's the important bit - typically a program is arranged so "headers" can be included by more than once source file.

Your debugger is being helpful in pinpointing the location of the original code.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, as I understand headers play completely no role during a
>   program's runtime. Headers are used solely by compilers during
>   compilation.

This is a misunderstanding, since headers are not a special kind of file. Headers (usually .h or .hpp) are not technical different than other source file - it is merely a convention that header files are supposed to be included and a lot of headers contain source code (just look at any STL file - which is thought of as a header file)